# Web3js 1.0.x: contract.at not a function

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to follow this flow to access a  contract that has been mined previously:

```
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJSON);

// instantiate by address
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);
```

Unfortunatly the contractInstance does not work and I get a contract.at is not a function error. I suspect it has something to do with web3js newest version but I am not sure what to use instead.

I have just tried:

```
var deployed = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonAbi, address)
```

But then when I try to call my public function on the contract I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

If I look into `deployed` every thing from the abi to the address is there, so it seems like the fetching of the contract actually worked.

Comment: How do you call your public function?

Answer (score 2):

`at` method is deprecated since web3.js v1.0.x.

Instead you can use this format:

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiInterface, contractAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a deployed contract at `address`, with *ABI* defined as `abiJSON`, using `web3@1.0.0-beta.35`, the corresponding code for calling a function specified in that contract is as follows:

Instancing `MyContract` as originally mentioned is correct. However, setting the contract address has changed in *Web3 1.0* [1]:

`var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJSON);
MyContract.options.address = address;`

Alternatively, setting the address during creation is also valid, as correctly done in the provided code:

`var deployed = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJSON, address);`

Other than the `at()` function not being available, the function `call` has also changed in *Web3 1.0* to the following [2]:

`MyContract.methods.myPublicFunction(<parameters>).call(<callback>);`

Example using the callback:

`MyContract.methods.myPublicFunction().call(function(error, result){ 
    console.error(error); 
    console.log(result);

}`

It is also possible to use the returned *Promise* a way to read back the results.

[1] https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#options-address
[2] https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Stay super!

/javi